# How to pass data from click event in inner loop in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

so here is my vue template

```
<template>
<div class="app-container">
  <el-dialog :visible="dialogVisible"
             title="View order"
             :before-close="() => dialogVisible = false">
    <order-form @success="handleAdd" @cancel="dialogVisible = false" />
  </el-dialog>
  <el-table v-loading="loading" :data="orders" border>
    <el-table-column prop="order.id" label="Id" />
    <el-table-column prop="order.fullName" label="Full Name" />
    <el-table-column prop="order.address.name" label="Address" />
    <el-table-column prop="order.status" label="Status" />
    <el-table-column label="View" prop="order.id" min-width="150">
      <el-col style="flex: 0">            
        <el-button icon="el-icon-plus" type="primary" @click="i want pass data from here">
          View Order
        </el-button>
      </el-col>
    </el-table-column>

  </el-table>
</div>
</template>
```

what I want to do is when i click the button i want to trigger a function
and pass the whole order object to a property so when the dialog is true 
I can pass the order object to the child component.
I have tried this

```
<el-button icon="el-icon-plus" type="primary" @click="senddata(order)">
```

and it doesn't work, it gives undefined  so it's not parsed.
thanks in advance.

this is my script

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";
import { getOrders } from "@/api/store";
import dataStore from "@/store/modules/data";
import { OrderView } from "../../../models";
import { OrderInput } from "@/models";
import DataModule from "@/store/modules/data";
  import OrderForm from "./form.vue";

type _OrderInput = OrderInput;

interface TableRowData {
  editMode: boolean;
  order: OrderView;
  editedOrder: _OrderInput;
}

  @Component({
    components: {
      OrderForm,
    },
  })
export default class Orders extends Vue {
    orders: TableRowData[] = [];
    testdata: any;
  loading = false;
  dialogVisible = false;
  searchKey = "";
  async created() {
    await DataModule.ensureLoaded();
    this.fetchData();
  }

  async fetchData() {
    this.loading = true;
    await dataStore.loadorders();
    if (dataStore.orders.hasLoaded) {
      this.orders = dataStore.orders.data.map(order => ({
        editMode: false,
        order,
        editedOrder: { ...order }
      }));
    }
    this.loading = false;
  }
  handleAdd() {
    this.dialogVisible = false;
  }
    senddata(id: any) {
      console.log(id);
      this.dialogVisible = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is ElementUI, I think you'll need to use a [custom column template](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#custom-column-template) with a scoped slot template.

For example

```html
<el-table-column label="View" min-width="150">
  <template slot-scope="{ row }">
    <el-col style="flex: 0">            
      <el-button icon="el-icon-plus" type="primary" @click="senddata(row.order)">
        View Order
      </el-button>
    </el-col>
  <template>
</el-table-column>
```

Here, `row` in the slot scope is the `TableRowData` in your `orders` array

Comment: Thank you soo much man, I had now idea about slot-scope , am new to vue. thanks again

Comment: It's not so much a [tag:vue.js] question as it is an [tag:element-ui] one. I really dislike that framework and its documentation is terrible

Comment: totally agree with you, it's freelance project requested with vuejs. I prefer Angular, so organized and structured although a bit more writing, but you know where to search in situations like this. Thanks again

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. I love Vue and think it's great but ElementUI is a mess. I'm not really a fan of any component libraries and prefer something like [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/)

Comment: ahh okay, i will see more about tailwind, another small question, i've tried to call v-bind:testdata in <order-form ... but it didnt work it gives me it's not existed, how is that? thanks again

Comment: Probably worth asking a new question about that one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61820344/how-to-send-object-to-child-component-in-vue-elementui